# Auto Reply to incoming calls by message using Shortcuts app

Tags: messages, shortcuts-app, ios

Is it possible to reply incoming calls by A fixed message (say: Call you later ) automatically using Shortcuts app ?

Like Do not disturb  for incoming messages in iOS 13.